# Discontinuous mapping between function spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $ C([0,1]) $ be a space of continuous real-valued functions over interval $[0,1]$ and $ \|f\|_2 = (\int_0^1|f|^2 \, dx)^{1/2} $ define a norm over this space. Prove that the following mapping:

$ L: C([0,1]) \rightarrow C([0,1]); ~ C(f) = f^2 $ is discontinuous.

So, let $ \epsilon >0 $ be fixed and $ \delta > 0 $ arbitrary. I'm supposed to find functions such that

$$\sqrt{ \int_0^1|f-g|^2 dx }< \delta,\text{ but }\sqrt{\int_0^1|f^2-g^2|^2} \geq \epsilon.$$

So the proof can just be done with an example, I just can't think of one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $f_n^2(0)=n^\frac{3}{4}$,$f_n^2(x)=0 \quad \forall x\in [\frac{1}{n},1]$ and linear on $[0,\frac{1}{n}]$. Let $f_n=\sqrt{f_n^2} \in C([0,1])$.

Note $f_n\to f=0$ in $L^2$ norm since $ \|f_n\|_2 = (\int_0^1|f|^2 \, dx)^{1/2}=(\int_0^1|f^2| \, dx)^{1/2}$ and $f^2\to f=0$ in $L^1$ norm, but $f^2_n$ doesn't converge to $f^2=0$ in $L^2$ norm.

Hence the operator $L$ is discontinuous since continuity implies $\forall f_n\to f, L(f_n)\to L(f)$.

Comment: Thank you! I was trying the same trick with $ f_n^2(0)=n $, but it didn't work out.